# What is the best way to make a good but simple line follower?

Tags: robotics

I am new in this site, and like you can see I want to do a line follower, not a clumsy and slow line follower, but a fast and "fancy".
I investigated about the PID method, but can someone explain me in simple words what is it.
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Have you already chosen/built the robot? what kind of hardware do you want to use? BTW, I suspect that PID will only be useful if you have a continuous/fluid way to sense the line and not just 3 infrared sensors like many basic line follow bots have.

Comment: The chasis... I have not make it yet, and i have 8 sensors in an array.

Comment: This might be a good tutorial for you to look at:

http://letsmakerobots.com/node/39972

Answer (score 2):

Did you check wikipedia, for example?

I doubt it is possible to describe a PID controller in simpler words than those used by [the article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller).

The [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller#Pseudocode) is quite simple and should be also very good for understanding the concept, when applied to a digital system.

See also the [limitations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller#Limitations_of_PID_control) of PID controllers.